# FCN-8 decoder in TensorFlow (Fully Convolutional Network)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, data-science

I am implementing FCN-8 decoder (assignment for deeplearning.ai advanced techniques in deep learning with Tensorflow, Computer Vision course, Week 3, Semantic Segmentation)

I implemented the code below, I suspect some dimensionality issues: running the test it falls at line:

**`o = tf.keras.layers.Add()([o, o2])`**

with error `ValueError: Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (8, 12, 11) (4, 6, 11)` so that I guess i am trying to concatenate objects with different shapes.

I copy below the corpse of the test as well, `FCN8()` method is safe imo.

Would you have any hint?

```
def fcn8_decoder(convs, n_classes):
  # features from the encoder stage
  f3, f4, f5 = convs

  # number of filters
  n = 512

  # add convolutional layers on top of the CNN extractor.
  o = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(n , (7 , 7) , activation='relu' , padding='same', name="conv6", data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(f5)
  o = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(o)
  o = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(n , (1 , 1) , activation='relu' , padding='same', name="conv7", data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(o)
  o = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(o)
  o = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(n_classes,  (1, 1), activation='relu' , padding='same', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(o)

  # Upsample `o` above and crop any extra pixels introduced
  o = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(n_classes , kernel_size=(4,4) ,  strides=(2,2) , use_bias=False )(f5)
  o = tf.keras.layers.Cropping2D(cropping=(1,1))(o)

  # load the pool 4 prediction and do a 1x1 convolution to reshape it to the same shape of `o` above
  o2 = f4
  o2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(n_classes , ( 1 , 1 ) , activation='relu' , padding='same')(o2)

  # add the results of the upsampling and pool 4 prediction
  o = tf.keras.layers.Add()([o, o2])

  # upsample the resulting tensor of the operation you just did
  o = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose( n_classes , kernel_size=(4,4) ,  strides=(2,2) , use_bias=False)(o)
  o = tf.keras.layers.Cropping2D(cropping=(1, 1))(o)

  # load the pool 3 prediction and do a 1x1 convolution to reshape it to the same shape of `o` above
  o2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(n_classes , ( 1 , 1 ) , activation='relu' , padding='same')(o2)

  # add the results of the upsampling and pool 3 prediction
  o = tf.keras.layers.Add()([o, o2])

  # upsample up to the size of the original image
  o = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(n_classes , kernel_size=(8,8) ,  strides=(8,8) , use_bias=False )(o)
  o = tf.keras.layers.Cropping2D(((0, 0), (0, 96-84)))(o)

  # append a sigmoid activation
  o = (tf.keras.layers.Activation('sigmoid'))(o)


  return o
```

TEST CODE

```
# TEST CODE

test_convs, test_img_input = FCN8()
test_fcn8_decoder = fcn8_decoder(test_convs, 11)

print(test_fcn8_decoder.shape)

del test_convs, test_img_input, test_fcn8_decoder
```

Comment: What are shapes of your `test_convs`? Also you twice manipulate `f5` and save in same `o`, maybe you missed some flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to first load the pool 3 prediction and then apply 1*1 conv

def fcn8_decoder(convs, n_classes):

## features from the encoder stage

f3, f4, f5 = convs

## number of filters

n = 512

## add convolutional layers on top of the CNN extractor.

o = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(n , (7 , 7) , activation='relu' , padding='same', name="conv6", data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(f5)
o = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(o)
o = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(n , (1 , 1) , activation='relu' , padding='same', name="conv7", data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(o)
o = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(o)
o = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(n_classes,  (1, 1), activation='relu' , padding='same', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(o)

## Upsample `o` above and crop any extra pixels introduced

o = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(n_classes , kernel_size=(4,4) ,  strides=(2,2) , use_bias=False )(f5)
o = tf.keras.layers.Cropping2D(cropping=(1,1))(o)

## load the pool 4 prediction and do a 1x1 convolution to reshape it to the same shape of `o` above

o2 = f4
o2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(n_classes , ( 1 , 1 ) , activation='relu' , padding='same')(o2)

## add the results of the upsampling and pool 4 prediction

o = tf.keras.layers.Add()([o, o2])

## upsample the resulting tensor of the operation you just did

o = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose( n_classes , kernel_size=(4,4) ,  strides=(2,2) , use_bias=False)(o)
o = tf.keras.layers.Cropping2D(cropping=(1, 1))(o)

## load the pool 3 prediction and do a 1x1 convolution to reshape it to the same shape of `o` above

o2=f3
o2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(n_classes , ( 1 , 1 ) , activation='relu' , padding='same')(o2)

## add the results of the upsampling and pool 3 prediction

o = tf.keras.layers.Add()([o, o2])

## upsample up to the size of the original image

o = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(n_classes , kernel_size=(8,8) ,  strides=(8,8) , use_bias=False )(o)
o = tf.keras.layers.Cropping2D(((0, 0), (0, 96-84)))(o)

## append a sigmoid activation

o = (tf.keras.layers.Activation('sigmoid'))(o)

return o